# Ajax requests with time parameters not working

Tags: ajax

I am trying to replicate in Python 3 the ajax requests I can see in Chrome Tools at [this](http://www.canada.com/entertainment/television/tv-listings/index.html#f=grid) address when changing the time slot of data in the EPG grid.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import re
import requests
             
session = requests.Session()

                
url_list = ['http://tvmds.tvpassport.com/snippet/white_label/php/grid.php?subid=postmedia&lu=36625D&wd=940&ht=445&mode=json&style=wh&st=1599019200&tz=America%2FToronto&lang=en&ctrlpos=top&items=90&numhours=5',
'http://tvmds.tvpassport.com/snippet/white_label/php/grid.php?subid=postmedia&lu=36625D&wd=940&ht=445&mode=json&style=wh&st=1599033600&tz=America%2FToronto&lang=en&ctrlpos=top&items=90&numhours=5',
'http://tvmds.tvpassport.com/snippet/white_label/php/grid.php?subid=postmedia&lu=36625D&wd=940&ht=445&mode=json&style=wh&st=1599048000&tz=America%2FToronto&lang=en&ctrlpos=top&items=90&numhours=5',
'http://tvmds.tvpassport.com/snippet/white_label/php/grid.php?subid=postmedia&lu=36625D&wd=940&ht=445&mode=json&style=wh&st=1599062400&tz=America%2FToronto&lang=en&ctrlpos=top&items=90&numhours=5',
'http://tvmds.tvpassport.com/snippet/white_label/php/grid.php?subid=postmedia&lu=36625D&wd=940&ht=445&mode=json&style=wh&st=1599076800&tz=America%2FToronto&lang=en&ctrlpos=top&items=90&numhours=5',
'http://tvmds.tvpassport.com/snippet/white_label/php/grid.php?subid=postmedia&lu=36625D&wd=940&ht=445&mode=json&style=wh&st=1599004800&tz=America%2FToronto&lang=en&ctrlpos=top&items=90&numhours=5']



for url in url_list:
    
    headers ={
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'tvmds.tvpassport.com',
    'Referer': 'http://www.canada.com/entertainment/television/tv-listings/index.html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
    }
                                         
    r = session.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    status_code = r.status_code
                                        
    data2 = r.content.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
    
    session.close()

    chan_data = re.findall(' channel row -->(.*?)<!--', data2, re.S)

    for chan in chan_data:
        
        if "\'tvm_chan_50\'" in chan:
        
            print(url)
            print(chan)
            print('-' * 150)
```

The code runs without error, but the `&st` parameter appears to be having no effect. This the timestamp of various times throughout the day.

I keep getting the same time slot of data returned of 7am to 9:30am roughly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit:

For clarity, the code itself is not falling over. My problem is the the ajax requests I am seeing in Chrome tools when using the time toggle buttons on the EPG referenced does not seem to be producing the same effect when the ajax API is either run in code, or copied and pasted directly into a web browser...

Comment: Does it work as expected if you get the url outside python?

Comment: no...if i copy and paste it into Chrome I have the same issue. I think the problem is more that I am perhaps pointing to the wrong API and/or using incorrect API params...

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with Python. Please edit your question.

Comment: ive amended title and tags. the rest stands.

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong in your Python code. You should make it clear that _"if i copy and paste it into Chrome I have the same issue. I think the problem is more that I am perhaps pointing to the wrong API and/or using incorrect API params"_ in your question, because otherwise people are going to waste time trying to figure out what's wrong with your Python code.

Comment: done - have amended